# Is there any commentary on principal Upanishads following the Samkhya doctrine?

Tags: upanishads, sankhya

I know that writing commentaries on Upanishads are the job of Vedantins. However, I personally feel Upanishads can be elegantly explained by the Samkhya doctrine. Just wondering whether some Samkhya Acharyas tried that.

Comment: The Samkhya doctrine is an ancient school. All modern day Hindus are followers of Vyasa.

Comment: I'd also like those commentaries same from Vaisheshika and other schools too. :)

Comment: Legitimate commentary on vedic literature can be ascribed to Purva mimamsa and Uttara mimamsa only . Sankya Dharshana is a philosophy of its  own accord.Despite the ancient/original  sutras of Kapila Maharishi are lost, and Sri.  Ishwara Krishna's karika being the primary text,its 24 tattvas has influenced yoga philosophy, charaka samhita an so on.Sankya does not define Ishwara(Paramatma)  unlike yoga etc., though kaivalya( interms of yukti dipika) pertains to one of the many disparate purushas,that does not affect Prakrithi functioning..,

Comment: akin to a dancer who does not stop dancing just because one of the audience has left. Though Dvaita and Visishtadvaita is in agreement with sankya wrt. Prakriti as real, they may differ reg. kaivalya, / Paramatma in principle.  IMO there is no commentary on (Prasthaana thraya) , in the light of sankya in its entirety